# How combine chunks of array into one array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

What i have:

```
var json = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: {
    title: 'yeah'
  }
}

var path = ['key3', 'title'];
```

What i want is combine chunks of 'path' array to have a path to json:

```
return json['key3']['title'];
```

Comment: right, have you tried something, like iterating the given path?

Comment: Assuming you want to return a reference to the resulting variable which lives at that location, which it looks like (as opposed to some sort of path string), then looping through the path array is the obvious way. What have you tried?

Comment: You can use `var result = path.reduce((r,k) => r[k],json);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can itterate over the path elements and find the right position like so:

```js
var json = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: {
    title: 'yeah'
  }
}

var path = ['key3', 'title'];

function getPath(json, ...path){
  if(Array.isArray(path[0])){ path = path[0];}
  var i = 0;
  while(path.length > i){
    var key = path[i++];
    json = json[key];
    if(json === undefined) return undefined;
  }
  return json;
}

console.log(getPath(json, path));
console.log(getPath(json, ...path));
console.log(getPath(json, 'key3', 'title'));
console.log(getPath(json, 'key1', 'title'));
console.log(getPath(json, 'doesNotExsist', 'title'));
console.log(getPath(json, 'key1'));
```